# Facebook developers app https is required for web-application?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

For my web application I want to login via Facebook. When I try to do login via Facebook it showing as https is required for my application. If no https it shown error as *Insecure Login Blocked: You can't get an access token or log in to this app from an insecure page. Try re-loading the page as https://*  So should I install ssl in my web application?

Comment: that means https is required right?

Comment: Look at the screenshot in the answer. You need to turn off the "Enforce HTTPS" switch if you do not want to use an SSL.

Comment: Please refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49400199/why-enforce-https-is-forcefully-set-as-yes/49778678#49778678