# How to fix 'Facebook has detected MyApp isn't using a secure connection to transfer information.' error in Laravel

Tags: laravel, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, laravel-socialite

[image]

I am trying to connect my app to facebook login with Laravel and socialite package.But i don't know why facebook show me this error. I searched internet but i couldn't find anything .How can i fix this error ?

I thought that if i make my connection with https it will work but after making https again error appears.

My code in laravel:

web.php

```
Route::get('login/{provider}', 'SocialController@redirect');
Route::get('login/{provider}/callback','SocialController@Callback');
```

SocialController.php

```
    public function redirect($provider)
    {
        return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
    }

    public function Callback($provider){

        $userSocial =   Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();
        $users       =   User::where(['email' => $userSocial->getEmail()])->first();
        if($users){
            Auth::login($users);
            return redirect('/');
        }else{$user = User::create([
                'username'          => $userSocial->getName(),
                'email'         => $userSocial->getEmail(),
                'provider_id'   => $userSocial->getId(),
                'provider'      => $provider,
            ]);
            return redirect()->route('home');
        }
    }
```

Comment: So “make connection with https” means what exactly - just accessing the site via `https://`, or did you make additional changes in the configuration?

Comment: @misorude, I think no i made connection with https://  but facebook show error again. Maybe this error mean something different

Comment: So what does the address bar show when you try to call the login dialog - the value of the `redirect_uri` parameter, is that actually an HTTPS URL?

Comment: when i try to login uri is like that 
https://www.facebook.com/v3.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=469859203797126&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstatusco.test%2Flogin%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&scope=email&response_type=code&state=5SmcNVacBJhR3OiPzSGsr9Urz0KUY7tTmfUmZrdG
I think u are right because in the uri http written

Comment: Probably just need to modify the configuration accordingly then, https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/socialite#configuration

Comment: thanks a lot .i change FACEBOOK_URL in .env this error solved . But now i have new error do u know solution of this https://i.imgur.com/7OGEQ1A.png?

Comment: You need to modify your settings in the app dashboard accordingly as well.

Comment: @misorude, thanks bro . Everything works now. U helped me a lot i was searching it two days

Comment: Does this answer your question? [facebook login on localhost without https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52712047/facebook-login-on-localhost-without-https)

Comment: Yes. It helped me solve this problem.

Comment: @MammadliAnar, but how can you force facebook to use https for redirect instead of http (which it uses now?)

Comment: I think problem was in generated link. Check .env file and correct http in there

Answer (score 35):

You can do "Create Test App" and replace your App ID and Secret using the test app.

[image]

Comment: this solved it for me.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is - Facebook will send sensitive data to provided `redirect_uri`, so it is ensuring this connection is private, by forcing you to use valid SSL.

As long as you do not setup a valid domain with proper certificate, Facebook won't let you use production API.

Comment: Where is this redirect_uri defined? I have a https ssl secure domain put in the App Domains, Site URL, Domains and Valid OAuth Redirect URIs in the Facebook console but it still uses `redirect_uri=http://domain` instead of https

Answer (score 3):

It looks like time expiration. I've just created another Facebook app and it works without that error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/download) to make your localthost https.
download and run **ngrok.exe**.

Then run command ngrok.exe http {port}. In most cases, it will be 8000.

Comment: Secure endpoint via ngrok required a paid plan.

Answer (score -6):

In case of angular : try to serve your app in secured socket layer **true** mode as Facebook is detecting insecure connection

Use the following command:

```
ng serve --ssl true
```