# Insecure connection on localhost

Tags: laravel, https, laravel-socialite

I am using Laravel 7 and utilizing Laravel socialite package for the first time for authenticating with facebook.

The problem is I am on localhost and when I am redirected to facebook I am getting error saying

```
Facebook has detected that XYZ isn't using a secure connection to transfer information.

Until XYZ updates its security settings, you won't be able to use Facebook to log in to it.
```

I tried to configure my xampp to run localhost on https by following these methods

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28658969/12168002
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mig9YPNiUZI

but none of them worked for me.

I watched few socialite installation videos and noticed that none of them was having secure connection but still able to authenticate user successfully.

Please highlight the actual cause of me getting this error and how can I fix this?

Comment: Check the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57372648/how-to-fix-facebook-has-detected-myapp-isnt-using-a-secure-connection-to-trans) question.

Comment: are you using Windows or Mac? If you're on the Mac then install ``Valet`` to secure the app.  More info https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/valet

Comment: I referred [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57372648/how-to-fix-facebook-has-detected-myapp-isnt-using-a-secure-connection-to-trans)  answer but didn't understand what to to do. will you please elaborate? @Bruno Pintos

Comment: I am using Windows @OMiShah