# Facebook has detected AngularAuth isn't using a secure connection to transfer information

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angularfire2, angularfire, angularfire5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlGeB.png)

how can I solve this problem

Comment: Just It's looks like time expirataion. [how-to-fix-facebook-has-detected-myapp-isnt-using-a-secure-connection-to-trans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57372648/how-to-fix-facebook-has-detected-myapp-isnt-using-a-secure-connection-to-trans)

Comment: I can't solve it right so